# Extracting objects attributes from Swagger JSON schema using jq

Tags: json, swagger, jq, openapi

I want to extract objects name and their attributes (`.properties`) from `.definitions` part of swagger json file, like:

```
{
  "definitions": {
    "Pet": {
      "type": "object",
      "required": ["pet_type"],
      "properties": {
        "pet_type": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      },
      "discriminator": {
        "propertyName": "pet_type"
      }
    },
    "Dog": {
      "allOf": [{
          "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Pet"
        }, {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "bark": {
              "type": "boolean"
            },
            "breed": {
              "type": "string",
              "enum": ["Dingo", "Husky", "Retriever", "Shepherd"]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

to:

```
object_name:
  attribute_name
```

like:

```
Pet:
  pet_type
Dog:
  bark
  breed
```

The point is `.properties` sometimes come directly after object name and sometimes as part of `allOf`, `anyOf`, or `oneOf`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this fit your needs?

```sh
jq -r '
  .definitions
  | to_entries[]
  | .key + ":", "  " + (
    .value
    | (., .allOf[], .anyOf[], .oneOf[] | .properties)? // {}
    | to_entries[].key
  )
'
```

```
Pet:
  pet_type
Dog:
  bark
  breed
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/L-luG8TpNa)

Comment: Thanks @pmf, it works perfectly

Comment: I am getting error jq: error: syntax error, unexpected INVALID_CHARACTER, expecting end of file (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
jq -r 
      
jq: 1 compile error
exit status 3

Comment: @HydPhani Here's an updated [demo](https://jqplay.org/s/D_en4zcXkT8). Try adapting it to your needs.